# Robolectric 2.x - dependent jars are downloading while running the tests

Tags: robolectric

How will I download all the robolectric dependent jars, to avoid runtime downloading and make it offline? I need to use Robolectric.buildActivity(), which is part of 2.x.x versions.

any idea on this ?

Comment: any idea on this ? still not resolved

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Robolectric 2.4 they added two system properties to allow you to tell the Robolectric test runner to use local copies of the dependencies. See the [Configuring Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/configuring/) page.

The settings are:

- robolectric.offline - Set to true to disable runtime fetching of jars
- robolectric.dependency.dir - When in offline mode, specifies a folder containing runtime dependencies

One way to figure out which files you need to copy to the dependencyDir, is to run `gradlew testDebug -i` (or maybe with `-d`) and watch the output to see which jars are being downloaded at runtime. Then copy them to a known location on your build machine. (Another way to see which files you need, is to look at SdkConfig.java and get the dependency jars mentioned there along with their dependencies.)

For the current Robolectric 3.0-rc2, these are the files it needs:

- accessibility-test-framework-1.0.jar
- android-all-5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1.jar
- icu4j-53.1.jar
- json-20080701.jar
- robolectric-annotations-3.0-rc2.jar
- robolectric-resources-3.0-rc2.jar
- robolectric-utils-3.0-rc2.jar
- shadows-core-3.0-rc2.jar
- sqlite4java-0.282.jar
- tagsoup-1.2.jar
- vtd-xml-2.11.jar

Copy these files to a known location, like say `/home/jenkins/robolectric-files/`, and then edit your `build.gradle` with something like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.withType(Test) {
        systemProperties.put('robolectric.offline', 'true')
        systemProperties.put('robolectric.dependency.dir', '/home/jenkins/robolectric-files/')
    }
}
```

Comment: hard-coding a specific user account like '/home/jenkins/' in your gradle file is bad, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved it for `org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0`

https://gist.github.com/kotucz/60ae91767dc71ab7b444

I downloads the runtime dependencies into the build folder and configures the tests to use it - see setting the system properties.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and found the cause to be the org.robolectric.Testrunner creating a org.robolectric.MavenCentral object, which declares a Maven repository using an Internet-url (Robolectric 2.3-release). Offline builds will not be able to access that url.

In my case I'm required to use a Maven repository proxy, so I replaced the url pointing to http://oss.sonatype.org with my local Maven repository proxy. That meant subclassing RobolectricTestRunner to org.robolectric.MyRobolectricTestRunner, and creating a custom MavenCentral object for it to use, and overriding the methods where RobolectricTestRunner  references its private MAVEN_CENTRAL object.

The source code for [RobolectricTestRunner](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/robolectric-2.3/src/main/java/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.java) and [MavenCentral](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/robolectric-2.3/src/main/java/org/robolectric/MavenCentral.java) are available on Robolectric's Github page.

Answer (score 0):

I used Robolectric version 3.0, and the dependency jars were downloaded from my repository, instead of sonatype.